# Alternate proofs of the inequality $\sum_{\text{cyclic}} \frac{x}{2x+y+z}\le \frac{3}{4}$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $x,y,z\in(0,\infty),$ prove the inequality,
$$\sum_{\text{cyclic}} \frac{x}{2x+y+z}\le \frac{3}{4}$$
I have a solution using the substitution $x+y=a,$ $y+z=b$ and $z+x=c$.
$$\frac{x}{2x+y+z}+\frac{y}{2y+z+x}+\frac{z}{2z+x+y}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{c+a-b}{c+a}+\frac{a+b-c}{a+b}+\frac{b+c-a}{b+c}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(3-\sum\frac{a}{b+c}\right)$$
Using [Nesbitt's Inequality](https://brilliant.org/wiki/nesbitts-inequality/),
$$\sum\frac{a}{b+c}\ge \frac{3}{2}\implies \frac{1}{2}\left(3-\sum\frac{a}{b+c}\right)\le \frac{3}{4}$$

---

Is there a simpler solution to this problem that I am completely oblivious to? This was part of a problem set with relatively easier (well known) problems and I wouldn't be allowed to 'state' the Nesbitt's Inequality without proof.

Comment: FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B2x%2By%2Bz%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7By%7D%7B2y%2Bz%2Bx%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bz%7D%7B2z%2Bx%2By%7D%20%5Cle%20%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B4%7D%24&p=1), I found the closely related [Prove that, if $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers $\frac {a} {2a+b+c}+ \frac {b} {2b+a+c}+\frac {c} {2c+a+b}<\frac{19}{25}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2522184/602049), and the AoPS thread [Qualms about Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1135390p5299391).

Comment: @JohnOmielan I don't know about Approach0 until today, thank you very much!

Comment: @JetfiRex You're welcome. For some details about Approach0, please read this meta [answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/602049).

Answer (score 1):

Alternate proof:

$$\sum_{\text{cyclic}} \frac{x}{2x+y+z}\le \frac{3}{4}\iff\sum_{\text{cyclic}} \frac{x+y+z}{2x+y+z}\ge \frac{9}{4}\\\iff 4(x+y+z)\sum_{\text{cyclic}} \frac{1}{2x+y+z}\ge 9\\\iff\sum_{\text{cyclic}}2x+y+z \sum_{\text{cyclic}} \frac{1}{2x+y+z}\ge 9$$

This is obvious by Cauchy-Schwartz, or AM-GM, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way: set $x+y+z=3$, then use Jensen's inequality with the concave function $t \mapsto \dfrac{t}{t+3}$…